# How to import a coded app directly onto my IPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have recently coded an IOS app on my windows PC using unity, I have exported it and set it to the right format, and I was just wondering wether there was a way to directly export it onto my IPhone without using the app store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an .ipa file, with the correct provisioning profile for your device, you can open it with iTunes and then sync with your phone.